# Can I call a function (not a module) from within shiny modile- can I pass the module reactive values as arguments of function

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinymodules

I am pretty new to Shiny modules.
I am trying to call a function (not a module) from one of my modules.
I would like to pass in the contents of my current reactive values (in my module) as arguments into the function.

The function make a sql query command based on the mrn number, startdate and enddate that is supposed to be fed into the function from 'modemtab'.

this is the error that I get:
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

I understand that this is because I'm passing the reactive values not contents of them into the function. My question is how can I pass the contents of these reactive values.

I included a piece of my code here.

Thanks.

```
app_server <- function(input, output,session) {
.
.
# getting csvupload_values from the first module and feeding it into the next.

csvupload_values <- callModule(csvupload, 'csv-upload')
callModule(modemtab,'mrntab', csvupload_values)


modemtab <- function(input, output, session, csvupload_values){

# the ouput$query is made in the UI part, but it's not the cause of issue.

output$query <- renderText({
    if(!is.null(csvupload_values$file_uploaded())){
      make_query(mrns = csvupload_values$file_uploaded()$mrns, 
                     startDate = csvupload_values$dates()[1], 
                     endDate = csvupload_values$dates()[2])


}




#This is the function called from within the second module (modemtab)
#this function is saved as a separate file in R folder 

    make_query <- function(...){
      glue_sql("
               select *
               FROM table
               WHERE
                 rgn_cd = {`rgn_cd`}
                 AND prdct_lne_cd = {`lob`}
                 AND ENCTR_STRT_TS >= {`startDate`}
                  AND ENCTR_END_TS <= {`endDate`}
                 "
               ,...
               ,.con = DBI::ANSI())
    }


csvuploadUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fileInput(ns('file'), "Choose CSV File",
              accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv")),


    dateRangeInput(
      ns('mrn_date_range'), label = 'Select the range of date:', 
      start = NULL, end = NULL, min = NULL,
      max = NULL, format = "mm/dd/yyyy", 
      startview = "month", weekstart = 0,
      language = "en", separator = " to ", width = NULL),


    # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
    checkboxInput(ns('header'), "Header", TRUE)

  )

}

# Module Server

csvupload <- function(input, output, session){

  userFile <- reactive({
    # If no file is selected, don't do anything
    validate(need(input$file, message = FALSE))
    input$file
  })

  dataframe <- reactive({
    read.csv(userFile()$datapath,
             header = input$header)
  })
```

Comment: Can you show the module `csvupload` ? It would be easier to help.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Hi, I added the csvupload to the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
csvupload_values <- callModule(csvupload, 'csv-upload')
callModule(modemtab,'mrntab', csvupload_values)
```

`csvupload_values` is a reactive conductor, so you can't do `callModule(modemtab,'mrntab', csvupload_values)` outside of a reactive context. You can do:

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  csvupload_values <- callModule(csvupload, 'csv-upload')

  observeEvent(csvupload_values(),{
    if(!is.null(csvupload_values())){
      callModule(modemtab, 'mrntab', csvupload_values)    
    }
  })

}
```

Now, `csvupload_values()` is a dataframe once you have uploaded the file, so I don't understand why you do `csvupload_values$file_uploaded()`. Here is a full example:

```
modemtabUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  textOutput(ns("query"))
}

modemtab <- function(input, output, session, csvupload_values){
  output$query <- renderText({
    colnames(csvupload_values())
  })
}

csvuploadUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fileInput(ns('file'), "Choose CSV File",
              accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv")),

    checkboxInput(ns('header'), "Header", TRUE),

    dateRangeInput(
      ns('mrn_date_range'), label = 'Select the range of date:', 
      start = NULL, end = NULL, min = NULL, max = NULL, format = "mm/dd/yyyy", 
      startview = "month", weekstart = 0,
      language = "en", separator = " to ", width = NULL)
  )
}

csvupload <- function(input, output, session){

  userFile <- reactive({
    # If no file is selected, don't do anything
    validate(need(input$file, message = FALSE))
    input$file
  })

  reactive({
    read.csv(userFile()$datapath, header = input$header)
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  csvuploadUI("csv-upload")
  modemtabUI("mrntab")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  csvupload_values <- callModule(csvupload, 'csv-upload')

  observeEvent(csvupload_values(),{
    if(!is.null(csvupload_values())){
      callModule(modemtab, 'mrntab', csvupload_values)    
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```